# Javascript Object Model SharePoint 2010 Item Level Permissions With Group

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom

I have been trying for some time now to do something that should be simple using **JAVASCRIPT** CSOM in SharePoint 2010. I have working code that can break list item permission and add a user to an item with a role. All I am trying to do is instead of adding a user, add an existing group. I have a handle to the group. The code executes without error, but it does not actually update the list item permissions on the item.

I have followed several of the MSDN articles but these are user based and the one group example is for a list and is creating the group which I am not doing.

Any examples of doing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Context Matters!!

No, I had made a blunder in my code that I did not notice before. I was trying to update items on a parent site from a subsite. Not sure why, but I moved all my code to the parent site and it worked as expected! Lesson Learned! Will have to add this to my blog as it is really cool!!

SP.ClientContext.get_current() is different than SP.ClientContext(siteurl) even if the siteurl is pointing to the correct site. Something to keep in mind!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds a group, it can be an Active Directory Group or a Sharepoint Group, to line item permition level using only javascript.

```
    var groupName = L_Menu_BaseUrl == "" ? 'domain\\all' : 'domain\\managing'; //group name

    function breakSecurityInheritanceChangeUser(id, groupName) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');

        var itemId = id;
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
        oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(true);
        this.oUser = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(groupName);


        var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);

        collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(clientContext.get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.administrator)); //full control

        oListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(oUser, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
        clientContext.load(oUser);
        clientContext.load(oListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { Success(groupName); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failure));
    }

    function Success(groupName) {
        var text = $("#hiddenSecurityItemSuccess").val(); //hidden for logging sucess
        var temp = groupName;
        text =+ temp + "<br/>";
        $("#hiddenSecurityItemSuccess").val(text);

    }

    function Failure(sender, args) {
        var text = $("#hiddenSecurityItemError").val(); //hidden for logging error
        var temp = args.get_message();
        text =+ temp + "<br/>";
        $("#hiddenSecurityItemError").val(text);
    }
```